# Does the Nested Interval Property imply a unique element?

Tags: real-analysis

Working on a problem. Assume a monotonically decreasing sequence, and the sequence approaches 0. Now prove the alternating series converges using the nested interval property. This is how the book does it.[image]

Now I basically did the same thing, but I quit after showing the infinite intersection of intervals isn't empty. The book goes on to show that there is a unique element in the infinite intersection. I thought this was implied because the nested interval property also shows completeness. Is this wrong?

Comment: It should be *intersection* of intervals, right?!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes must be a typo in the book.

Comment: Note that $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\left[-1-\frac1n,1+\frac1n\right]=[-1,1]$. So, no, the intersection doesn't have to consist of a single point.